the options you have to express anger

The goal in anger management is to increase the options you have to
express anger in a healthy way                                                                                                                                                                                   (from 'Healthy Anger: How to Help
Children and Teens Manage Their Anger')

In the sentence above, I want to know more about 'the options you have to express anger in a healthy way.'
We could put the antecedent 'the options' into the relative clause and make a sentence, 'You have the options to express anger in a healthy way.' Then, in this sentence, what is the exact role of 'to express anger in a healthy way'?

Infinitival Purpose clause in Adverbial usage: 'You have the options to express anger in a healthy way.'='You have [the options] in order to express anger in a healthy way.' That is, 'to express anger in a healthy way' is not inside the noun phrase headed by 'options'.

Infinitival Complement clause in Adjectival usage: 'You have [the options to express anger in a healthy way].' That is, 'to express anger in a healthy way' is inside the noun phrase headed by 'options'.


These two have subtly different meanings. Which one do you think is correct?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

This corresponds to moving a weighty relative clause modifying a noun phrase to after the verb:

All kinds of problems that smaller animals or plants do not have to
cope with  arise. [sounds clunky]
=
All kinds of problems [that smaller animals or plants do not have to
cope with] arise.
                                                                         → → → → →
All kinds of problems arise [that smaller animals or plants do not
have to cope with] arise.

[example courtesy of John Lawler]
...............................
In this case, the noun phrase has a qualifying to-infinitival, which also gets postposed:

The goal in anger management is to increase the options to express
anger in a healthy way you have. [sounds awful]
                                                                         → → → → →
The goal in anger management is to increase the options you have to
express anger in a healthy way.

The first transformation, at least,  is known as 'extraposition [or postposition; CGEL] from noun phrase'.
